# Python list: if a pair of numbers equals 0 return the positions of the elements

Tags: python, python-2.7, nested-lists

I am trying to write a python functions that takes in a list or array. if any two numbers in the list or array equal to zero, I want to return the positions of those two numbers.

Here is what I have so far. I loop through the list and have a nested loop of the same list to test if the outer iterator plus the nested iterator == 0: if yes then I am trying to return the positions of the two numbers that == 0. but it just gives me the actual two numbers instead. whats strange is the output below (even though it is not what I want) should be (3,-3). Any input would be greatly appreciated

```
def twosum(nums):
    for x in nums:
        for y in nums:
            if x + y == 0:
                return nums[x],nums[y]
print twosum([1, 3, 5, -3])
output  = (-3, 3)
```

Comment: If `x` is an element of `nums`, what is `nums[x]`? Go back in your course material and check what the brackets do, if you don't remember.

Comment: @user2357112 i am aware it is an index but I would think the first number should be 3 not -3.

Comment: @ziggy: If `x` is 3, what is `nums[x]`? It's not 3.

Comment: ahhh yes got it. the nested loop through me off a bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) while iterating over the list like:

```
def twosum(nums):
    for i, x in enumerate(nums):
        for j, y in enumerate(nums):
            if x + y == 0:
                return i, j
```

However this logic can be further optimised as:

```
def twosum(nums):
    for i, x in enumerate(nums):
        if -x in nums[i:]:  # check '-'ive of the number in non-iterated list
            return x, -x
```

Comment: This is the better answer that doesn't add an extra linear component to the performance and which handles duplicates in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You would do `return nums.index(x), nums.index(y)`

Comment: Technically works, but using `index` is a bad habit to get into. It requires rescanning the list to find the element, which is unnecessary and catastrophically slow if done repeatedly in a loop.